# Hibernate cannot resolve type with enum

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, enums

I have two entities and one with a field of a specific enum. Now I want to retrieve all that have a specific enum value.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AlarmEvent")
@XmlRootElement
public class AlarmEvent implements Identifiable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "guid")
    @Column(name = "Id", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AlarmType_Id")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(EntityAdapter.class)
    private AlarmEventDefinition alarmType;

    @Column(name = "Timestamp", nullable = false)
    private Date timestamp;

    @Override
    @XmlTransient
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return id;
    }

    public AlarmEventDefinition getAlarmType() {
        return alarmType;
    }

    public void setAlarmType(AlarmEventDefinition alarmType) {
        this.alarmType = alarmType;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

and the second entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AlarmEventDefinition")
@XmlRootElement
public class AlarmEventDefinition implements Identifiable {
    public static enum AlarmEventDefinitionType {
        Start, End, Trigger, Report
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "Name_DE", length = 256)
    private String nameDe;

    @Column(name = "Type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AlarmEventDefinitionType type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alarmType", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @XmlTransient
    private List<AlarmEvent> events;

    public List<AlarmEvent> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNameDe() {
        return nameDe;
    }

    public void setNameDe(String nameDe) {
        this.nameDe = nameDe;
    }

    public AlarmEventDefinitionType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(AlarmEventDefinitionType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Now I want to do this

```
List<AlarmEvent> result = (List<AlarmEvent>) session.createCriteria(AlarmEvent.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("alarmType.type", AlarmEventDefinitionType.Trigger))
        .list();
```

To retrieve all AlarmEvents thiers AlarmEventDefinitions type is Trigger.
Hibernate says:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   alarmType.type of: datamodel.AlarmEvent

Answer (score 0):

You just have an `alarmType` property defined in the `AlarmEvent` class, there is no `alarmType.type`. That's the error message is saying.

You need to extend the criteria to the associated class `AlarmEventDefinition`.  The code should be something like this:

```
List<AlarmEvent> result = (List<AlarmEvent>) session.createCriteria(AlarmEvent.class)
        .createCriteria("alarmType").add(Restrictions.eq("type", AlarmEventDefinitionType.Trigger))
        .list();
```

Comment: alarmType is instance of AlarmEventDefinition. AlarmEventDefinition has a field type (the enum) so why shouldnt there be a alarmType.type?

**Navigation**: AlarmEvent --alarmType--> AlarmEventDefinition --type--> AlarmEventDefinitionType

Comment: see my comment. property type is of class AlarmEventDefinition not AlarmEventDefinition**Type**

Comment: @Coxer. Yes I overlooked this at first, but the updated answer should deal with this.